# Issues with unicode characters whiles executing python script in unix

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

When I am running below code in python(2x or 3x), this is giving my desired output for the firstname i.e. "David A".

However when I run same script in unix, this is returing additional single quote in the output as : "'David A"

Can someone share the reason why unix is behaving differently and how to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance to all for your help

```
import json

def club_attribute_values(filter_value,uris,all_values,key_value):
    values = []
    for val in uris:
        value =(json.dumps(str([x[filter_value] for x in all_values if val in x[key_value]])[2:-2]))

        values.append(value)

    return ("$#".join(values))

Frst_Nm_all_v = [{u'type': u'FirstName', u'value': u'David A'}]

FirstNm_v =[u'FirstName']

Frst_Nm = club_attribute_values('value', FirstNm_v, Frst_Nm_all_v, 'type')

print(Frst_Nm)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested it on Debian Stretch with different Python versions and the output is as follows:

Python 2.7.13 (Debian package):

```
"'David A"
```

Python 3.5.3 (Debian package):

```
"David A"
```

Python 3.7.4 (Compiled from source):

```
"David A"
```

Are you sure that the result is on both Python versions the same?
What Unix version are you using?